# Vuex state changing with mutation - apollo graphql query

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router, apollo

I have a form where the user edits the object - in my case, metadata about a story - after it is loaded from GraphQL. However, when I use my vue-router guard to check if the story has been changed, the story state is always the modified value.

### Vuex `story.js`

```
...
  getters: {
    ...formSubmit.getters,
    getStory: (state) => {
     return  state.story},
    getEditedStory: (state) => state.editedStory,
    getStoryDescription: (state) => {
      return state.story.description
    }
  },
  mutations: {
    ...formSubmit.mutations,
    setStory(state, payload) { 
      state.story = payload 
    },
    setEditedStory(state, payload) { 
      state.editedStory = payload 
    }
  },
...
```

## Form component

```
   export default {
   ...
   apollo: {
      story: {
        query: gql`query GetStory($id: ID!) {
          story(id: $id) {
            name
            summary
            description
          }
        }`,
        variables() {
          return {
            id: this.id
          }
        },
        result({ data}) {
          this.setText(data.story.description)
          this.setStory(data.story)
          this.setEditedStory(data.story)
        },
      }
    },
...
```

In my form I have the values mapped with `v-model`:

```
    <v-text-field 
        v-model="story.name"
        class="mx-4"
        label="Add your title..."
        single-line
        :counter="TITLE_TEXT_MAX_LENGTH"
        outlined
        solo
        :disabled="updateOrLoadInProgress"
      />
```

However, for some reason whenever I call `this.getStory` its value is modified accordingly to the v-model. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I still don't quite understand why, it seems like the changes to the apollo variable `story` affect the `store.story` values with using the mutations to set them.

I've modified the initial setters to be like this:

```
          this.setText(data.story.description)
          let loadedStory = {
            name: data.story.name,
            description: data.story.description,
            summary: data.story.summary,
          }
          this.setStory(loadedStory)
          this.setEditedStory(data.story)
        },
```

which seems to prevent the `state.story` from following the changes to the apollo created `story` variable. This seems like unexpected behaviour, and I don't quite understand what part of javascript object assignment makes this work this way.